# How to teach mass center for young people

Tags: geometry

Could anyone recommend me some software that helps me teach about the `centroid` of an object?

Something that was dynamic on the computer screen.

Destined for 18 years of age.

Comment: How young? Five? Ten? Fifteen? You don't need software; you could use a [piece of cardboard and a string](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/x-marks-the-spot-finding-the-center-of-mass/).

Comment: Wouldn't "center of mass" be a physics concept and not a mathematical concept?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-D1kYXpZ4h4 is fun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this simple [Center of Mass Builder](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/Physics-Interactives/Balance-and-Rotation/COM-Builder/Center-Of-Mass-Interactive)
is what you had in mind?

---

[image: Snapshot]

---

As one click-adds (blue) mass to an object, the center of mass updates dynamically. Then you can pin a swivel point with the (green) pin, and the shape
swings around that point under the influence of gravity.

---

[image: Swivel]

---

Answer (score 3):

If you or your student(s) are aquainted with Geogebra, you can define geometrical objects in 2D and subject the object to the function [Centroid](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Centroid_Command), which provides you with a point.

You may want to check out the community's pertinent ressources on https://www.geogebra.org/search/perform/search/centroid